Can gravitational energy be localized in the case of plane waves?
Reading Dirac's "General Theory of Relativity", Chap. $33$ "Gravitational waves". He shows that in a weak gravitational field ($g_{\mu\nu}$ approximately constant), using harmonic coordinates, we have a wave equation $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\rho\sigma,\mu\nu}\approx \eta^{\mu\nu}g_{\rho\sigma,\mu\nu}=0$.
He also shows that the Einstein energy-momentum pseudotensor for a plane wave with wave vector $l_\mu$ is
$$16\pi {t_\mu}^\nu = \frac{1}{2}\left(u_{\alpha\beta}u^{\alpha\beta} - \frac{1}{2}u^2\right) l_\mu l^\nu$$
where $u_{\mu\nu}$ is the derivative of the function $g_{\mu\nu}$ of the single variable $l_\sigma x^\sigma$, and $u=u^\mu_\mu$.
Dirac concludes:
$\quad\quad$ "We have a result for ${t_\mu}^\nu$ that looks like a tensor. This means that ${t_\mu}^\nu$ transforms like a tensor under those transformations that preserve the character of the field consisting only of waves moving in the direction $l_\sigma$, so that the $g_{\mu\nu}$ remain functions of the single variable $l_\sigma x^\sigma$. Such transformations must consist only in the introduction of coordinate waves moving in the direction $l_\sigma$, of the form $$x^{\mu'}=x^\mu+b^\mu$$ where $b_\mu$ is a function of $l_\sigma x^\sigma$. With the restriction that we have waves moving only in one direction, gravitational energy can be localized."
$\quad\quad$ It is usually understood that the equivalence principle makes it impossible to localize gravitational energy-momentum. If there were a gravitational field energy-momentum tensor, it would vanish in locally inertial coordinates, hence it would vanish everywhere. That's why there are only pseudotensors of various kinds that satisfy $\left( [t^{\mu\nu}+T^{\mu\nu}]\sqrt{-g}\right)_{,\nu}=0$.
How can Dirac be right, in view of the equivalence principle? What exactly is he saying here?
